# According to Dvaita philosophy, how does a Jivatma view another Jivatma in Vaikuntha?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, atma, dvaita

As per my understanding, according to Dvaita philosophy Jivatma enters the Vaikuntha Loka but the Jivatma doesn't become Paramatma. It is also known that in Vaikuntha loka the primary duty of Jivatma is to pray to the Paramatma.

[Here](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/6/30) Paramatma says that :

> For one who sees Me everywhere and sees everything in Me, I am never
>   lost, nor is he ever lost to Me.

Suppose me and my friend enter the Vaikuntha. We both pray to the Paramatma.

My questions are:

Will my friend be able to see and hear me in Vaikuntha?

If yes, will my friend see and hear me as Parmatma or Jeevatma?(In other words will my friend consider me a Jeevatma or Parmatma?)

Finally, if my friend will be able to see and hear me in Vaikuntha Loka then can we say that Jeevatma can see and hear without the physical body?

Comment: You should first ask whether the bodies of dwellers in Vaikhuntha made up of Panch - Tattva or not?

Comment: Your primary duty in Vaikuntha is to serve the Lord Vishnu and not to pray to him. Yes, your friend will be able to see and hear you, and you will be able to see and hear him also. You and your friend are jivatmas, you will know that in Vaikuntha. The Lord Vishnu (Krishna) is paramatma. You will not think that you and your friends are paramatma. There is no need to have the body to be able to see and hear. Jivatma has an ability to see and hear in itself, that ability does not depend on the body. ...

Comment: ... However a jivatma can assume the body in the Vaikuntha so that he can use it to serve the Lord and to interact with other jivas in Vaikuntha. The body in Vaikuntha is made of pure spirit, it's non-material body. It's spiritual body.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa Thanks. Can you provide me the links to the source where it says body in Vaikuntha is made of pure spirit?  If my friend sees me as Jeevatma then it violates what God has said. God has said- "For one who sees Me everywhere and sees everything in Me, I am never lost, nor is he ever lost to Me."

Comment: *Can you provide me the links to the source where it says body in Vaikuntha is made of pure spirit?* -- for that you should ask a new question on this Hi SE website: *Are the bodies of souls in Vaikuntha made of pure spirit?*

Comment: *If my friend sees me as Jeevatma then it violates what God has said. God has said ...* No, it does not violate Lord Krishna's words. That verse does not say that Lord Krishna is the only thing that exists in the world, so that we should see only him everywhere, and not other things. That verse just means that Lord Krishna is everywhere and everything is in him, namely the whole universe is in him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you transcend the physical realm, verbal communication becomes redundant. People communicate through thoughts, and once Vaikuntha is reached, the only language known to them is "prema".

Basically they say that once in Vaikuntha, the soul acquires bodies of Vishnu and are with their consorts, in eternal bhakti towards the "real" Vishnu. Here "real" is within quotes because unlike Advaita, Dvaita says that jivatma and Paramatma are never same.

In the Madhya-lila section of the Chaitanya-caritamrita (21.55-57), the spiritual planets are described as larger than we can imagine, larger than any material universe. Each planet is also made of spiritual bliss. All of the inhabitants are associates of the Supreme Lord. And, in Chapter 20 (257-258), the spiritual world is referred to as the abode of the pastimes of the eternal spiritual energy.

> Srimad-Bhagavatam (3.15.16–23)
>
> “In those Vaikuntha planets there are many forests which are very
>   auspicious. In those forests the trees are wish-fulfilling trees, and
>   in all seasons they are filled with flowers and fruits because
>   everything in the Vaikuntha planets is spiritual and personal.
>
> “In the Vaikuntha planets the inhabitants fly in their airplanes,
>   accompanied by their wives and consorts, and eternally sing of the
>   character and activities of the Lord, which are always devoid of all
>   inauspicious qualities. While singing the glories of the Lord, they
>   deride even the presence of the blossoming madhavi flowers, which are
>   fragrant and laden with honey.
>
> “When the king of bees hums in a high pitch, singing the glories of
>   the Lord, there is a temporary lull in the noise of the pigeon, the
>   cuckoo, the crane, the cakravaka, the swan, the parrot, the partridge,
>   and the peacock. Such transcendental birds stop their own singing
>   simply to hear the glories of the Lord.
>
> “Although flowering plants like the mandara, kunda, kurabaka, utpala,
>   campaka, arna, punnaga, nagakeshara, bakula, lily, and parijata are
>   full of transcendental fragrance, they are still conscious of the
>   austerities performed by Tulasi, for Tulasi is given special
>   preference by the Lord, who garlands Himself with Tulasi leaves.
>
> “The inhabitants of Vaikuntha travel in their airplanes made of lapis
>   lazuli, emerald, and gold. Although crowded by their consorts, who
>   have large hips and beautiful smiling faces, the male inhabitants
>   cannot be stimulated to passion by their mirth and beautiful charms.
>
> “The ladies in the Vaikuntha planets are as beautiful as the goddess
>   of fortune herself. Such transcendentally beautiful ladies, their
>   hands playing with lotuses and their leg bangles tinkling, are
>   sometimes seen sweeping the marble walls, which are bedecked at
>   intervals with golden borders, in order to receive the grace of the
>   Supreme Personality of Godhead.
>
> “The goddesses of fortune worship the Lord in their own gardens by
>   offering Tulasi leaves on the coral-paved banks of transcendental
>   reservoirs of water. While offering worship to the Lord, they can see
>   on the water the reflection of their beautiful faces with raised
>   noses, and it appears that they have become more beautiful because of
>   the Lord’s kissing their faces.
>
> “It is very much regrettable that unfortunate people do not discuss
>   the description of the Vaikuntha planets.”

In this way we can understand that the spiritual realm is not some form of nothingness, as some people may imagine. It is further described that there are millions of Vaikuntha planets, each with a form or expansion of the Supreme Being who resides on it. Each resident of the spiritual world goes to whichever planet has the form of God to which he or she is most attracted. Each Vaikuntha planet is self-effulgent, and many millions of times brighter than the sun. Material time and the modes of nature have no influence in the spiritual realm. There is no birth, death, old age, or disease, and no past, present, or future. Time is conspicuous by its absence. Everything, including the homes, trees, animals, and plants, are all eternal. It is full of beauty and bliss.

So to answer your question, once you reach Vaiktuntha, you and your friend will lose the identity of you and your friend, which was there only in the material realm. This is because you'll lose all your ego, and become one with the Supreme Lord. You'll also form a sense of Oneness with every other jivatma around you, knowing yourself as nothing but a spark of the Lord's energy, which ultimately converges into the Lord Himself, knowing your true identity as the Absolute Consciousness - Brahman, who is formless, yet are all forms contained in it.

P.S. For those of you confused with my mixing of philosophies, please note that I categorize myself to be an Advaitin Vaishnava.